# Store data at game closing time Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-lifecycle

I want to store the data exactly when Application.Quit() method get called.
Basically I want one callback method that get called one time during application life cycle, just when application killed by operating system of the device.

With iOS, I managed to work with following line of code:

```
void OnApplicationQuit()
{

    //if (pauseStatus)
    //{
    DataStorage.StoreLastOpenedDay(DateTime.Now.Day);
    DataStorage.StoreLastOpenedMonth(DateTime.Now.Month);
    DataStorage.StoreLastOpenedYear(DateTime.Now.Year);
    //}
}
```

But I got information that in Android, OnApplicationQuit method didn't get called by the running activity.

So what is alternative exist in Android for implementing same thing as like iOS? I can't use OnApplicationPause method because it get called multiple times when any external process happen when your application is running for ex. phone call, in app purchase related popups etc...
I want code to be executed only once when application get killed.

Please share your side suggestions about this.

Comment: Gave an upvote to the question after seeing a downvote, completely undeserved. I wonder sometimes why people downvotes legit questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Android, `Application.Quit()` calls `OnApplicationQuit()`, but only from inside the Unity runtime.

This means that if you have the application paused in background, and the OS decides to kill it, `OnApplicationQuit()` will not be called at all.

Basically, to ensure that your app saves the data, you'll need to juggle with `OnApplicationPaused()` and `OnApplicationFocus()`, but this means that you won't be able to perform the save exactly once per lifetime of the app.

Comment: Also I have tried with placing code just above Application.Quit() but mostly Android user pressing Home button of device so in this condition too, event not get called :(

Comment: Exactly, so your best bet as I said in my answer is to save your data everytime `OnApplicationFocus(bool hasFocus)` has `!hasFocus`.

Comment: After doing proper research in multiple places, I can say that at present there is no way exist to detect application kill / destroy in Android - For my solution, I have implemented another way to handle same thing, On application start I have managed my code.